# NSString find the symbol got crashed

Tags: objective-c, xcode, nsstring, nsregularexpression

Everytime I will get a string from my server as:

> "&abc;123:342:431:234& &xyz;232:2344:433:434& &pqr;234:453:534:3445&"

but sometimes I'll get

> "&pqr;234:453:534:3445& &abc;123:342:431 &xyz;232:2344:433:434&"

I want to discard those messages (without ends with "&") ex:`&abc;123:342:431`. I tried but I don't know where I am making mistakes.

Here is my code:

```
- (BOOL)ashCheckandsemiclonCheck:(NSString *)string {
    if([string rangeOfString:@"&abc"].location != NSNotFound) {
        NSLog(@"is here");
        NSString *pattern = @"&abc[^&]+&";
        NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:pattern
                                                                               options:0 error:NULL];

        [regex enumerateMatchesInString:string options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [string length])
                             usingBlock:^(NSTextCheckingResult *result, NSMatchingFlags flags, BOOL *stop) {
                                 NSRange range = [result range];
                                 matched = [string substringWithRange:range];

                                 NSLog(@"%@", matched);
                             }];
        NSLog(@"filtered Message :%@", matched);
        int times = [[matched componentsSeparatedByString:@"&"] count] - 1;
        NSLog(@"counted times :%i", times);

        if (times == 2) {
            return TRUE;
        } else {
            return FALSE;
        }       
    } else {   
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

---

I want to call this argument if I have two `&` but in my code I get error `NSLog(@"is here");`. As I said sometimes I'll get half message. Can anyone tell me where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm reading your question correctly, it seems you just need to test whether a message string is valid by checking it begins and ends with '&'. The way I'd do that is to write something like this:

```
 NSString* testMessage = @"&bfjhfbgfjhb&";
 NSString* firstCharacter = [testMessage substringToIndex:1];
 NSString* lastCharacter  = [testMessage substringFromIndex:testMessage.length - 1];

 if (([firstCharacter isEqualToString:@"&"]) &&
      [lastCharacter isEqualToString:@"&"]){

    //This is a valid message. Proceed.

 }else{

   //This is not a valid message. Discard.

 }
```

## Update

Okay, based on your question edit/update, I edited your code -- and in particular your regex pattern string -- to do what I *think* you want, which is to check that the '&abc...' subsection of your message begins and ends with the '&' character:

```
-(BOOL) ashCheckandsemiclonCheck :(NSString *)string;
{

    if([string rangeOfString:@"&abc"].location !=NSNotFound)
    {
        NSLog(@"is here");

        NSString *pattern = @"&abc[^&\\s]+[^\\s]";

        NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:pattern
                                                                           options:0 error:NULL];
        NSString* __block matched;
        [regex enumerateMatchesInString:string options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [string length])
                         usingBlock:^(NSTextCheckingResult *result, NSMatchingFlags flags, BOOL *stop) {
                             NSRange range = [result range];
                             matched = [string substringWithRange:range];

                             NSLog(@"Matched: %@", matched);

                         }];

        NSLog(@"filtered Message :%@", matched);
        int times =[[matched componentsSeparatedByString:@"&"]count]-1;
        NSLog(@"counted times :%i",times);

        if(times ==2){
            return YES;
        }else  
        {
            return NO;
        }       
    }
    else
    {   
        return NO;
    }
}
```

Also changed your BOOL returns to Objective-C standard YES and NO rather than TRUE and FALSE.

Hope that does what you need.

Comment: thanks for your info . works really great :) i have a doubt " NSString* __block matched;" how i declare this as a global variable , because if i want to use "matched" string outside . I tried to declare "NSString *matched;". i am getting null string , because its not matching with "__block matched".